# Show results from certain record

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli, html-table

I have searched for this and keep getting errors no matter what I try.

The main error I get is:

> mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given

I have created a page showing all records. The user then selects one record to edit and the id is passed on to this page which would show all the fields in a form/table. a few of the fields are readonly so can not be modified.
What I am trying to achieve is to show the results in a table so that they can be edited and then sent to the database and updated. I was thinking of sending it to another file to update and then send them back to view the results page.

```
<form action = 'modify2.php' method = 'post'>
    <table border="1">  
    <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid #000000;">
    <strong>User ID</strong>
    <strong>Username</strong>
    <strong>Password</strong>
    <strong>Email</strong>
    <strong>Name</strong>
    <strong>Submitted By</strong>
    <strong>Memeber Since</strong>
    </tr>

    <?PHP
    //error check to see what results are obtained
    echo '<br />sql code = '.$sql.'<br/>'; // this works bot the $result 
    shows nothing
    //die();

    //fetch object array and put into a row
    //while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))  
    { 
        ?>
        <tr><td><label>User ID :</label></td>
        <td><input type = 'text' name = 'id' id = 'id' value='<?PHP echo $row["id"];?>' readonly/></input><br /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>Username</strong></td>
        <td><input type = 'text' name = 'username' id = 'username' value='<?PHP echo $row["username"];?>'/></input><br /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>password :</label></td>
        <td><input type = 'text' name = 'password' id = 'password' value='<?PHP echo $row["password"];?>'/></input><br /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>email :</label></td>
        <td><input type = 'text' name = 'email' id = 'email' value='<?PHP echo $row["email"];?>'/></input><br /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>Real Name :</label></td>
        <td><input type = 'text' name = 'Name' id = 'Name' value='<?PHP echo $row["Name"];?>'/></input><br /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>submitted by :</label></td>
        <td><input type = 'text' name = 'submittedby' id = 'submittedby' value='<?PHP echo $row["submittedby"];?>' readonly/></input><br /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>trn_date :</label></td>
        <td><input type = 'text' name = 'trn_date' id = 'trn_date' value='<?PHP echo $row["trn_date"];?>' readonly/></input></td></tr>
        <?PHP
     } 
    //close table here
    ?>
    <tr><td colspan='2'><div align='center'><input type = 'submit' value ='Modify Record' name = 'submit'/></td></tr>
    </form></div>
    </table>
```

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). It expects an argument of type [`mysqli_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) that is returned by a call to [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);` first to you can use

```
// Associative array
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```